# SiT! plugin to share files with clients

Tags: gratis, open-source, php, help-desk, file-server

I am considering using [SiT! (Support Incident Tracker)](http://sitracker.org/) as a helpdesk platform.

I would love to use this same platform to share files with clients: contracts, deliverables, etc.

Requirements:

- One folder for one client
- Client only need to log in once, no need to log in to each system (helpdesk, download)
- Free
- Open Source
- No SaaS, no dependency on any third-party server
- Works with SiT! but if no solution is available I can consider switching to another open source PHP helpdesk platform

If there is a way to achieve this natively with SiT! that would be perfect.